# Python for all orders of specific values that sum to 1

Tags: python, python-3.x, permutation

I'm writing an app dealing with some music theory and need to programmatically determine every way in which various specific note values can be arranged inside a single measure where each arrangement of those note values adds up to exactly 1.

The simplest case is a single note with a value of 1 inside a measure. But I need to take into account at least each of these values:

1

0.5

0.25

0.125

The outcome I'm looking for would let me identify the following possible orderings that each add up to 1. These kinds of cases:

| 1 |

|.25, .5, .25 |

|.25, .25., .5 |

| .5, .25, .125, .125 |

|.125, .125, .125, .125, .125, .125, .125, .125 |

etc....

NOTE: At least one post I found on here gets me a solution but it cuts out the repeating values that add up to 1 -- for example, it doesn't give this case as a result |.125, .125, .125, .125, .125, .125, .125, .125 |

I was initially trying to get a list using the variables I have commented out in my code below and wanted the solution to look something more like this (although I made up this order for this example):

[w, hh, hqh, qeqqe, eeqqee, qeqeq... ]

I couldn't figure out how to do that.

In total, I think there should be 44 possibilities, but I don't know the best way generate these with code.

Nor do I even know the best way to try to solve the problem since it seems like there might be a more mathematically interesting and efficient way to approach this.

What I have right now is using permutations of strings representing each value ordering and it gets me in the right direction. But any help and ideas for better solutions are greatly appreciated!!

```
from itertools import permutations

### Note values ###

'''
w = 1
h = 0.5
q = 0.25
e = 0.125
'''

e8 = ['eeeeeeee']
eq7 = [''.join(p) for p in permutations('eeeeeeq')]
eq6 = [''.join(p) for p in permutations('eeeeqq')]
eq5 = [''.join(p) for p in permutations('qqqee')]
eh5 = [''.join(p) for p in permutations('eeeeh')]
q4 = ['qqqq']
qh3 = [''.join(p) for p in permutations('qqh')]
h2 = ['hh']
w1 = ['w']

allPossible = list(set.union(*map(set, [e8, eq7, eq6, eq5, eh5, q4, qh3, h2, w1])))

print(len(allPossible))
print(allPossible)
```

Comment: You'd probably be better off using the `fractions` package rather than floating point.  If you know all your denominators are powers of two, then floating point should be exact (as long as the range is limited), but fractions still seem like a better approach.

Comment: As @TomKarzes says, `fractions` is a natural idea here.  As an alternative to using fractions, check if the distance of the sum to 1 is less than some small threshold. It is a major source of bugs to use `==` when dealing with floats.

Comment: Thanks to both of you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I do not have all my knowledge about permutations and stuff ready, I can help you with the first part of the question. That is, what are all the combinations possible to equal the value of 1?

I would suggest to put all the note values in a list. Then iterate through this list, such that all combinations are covered.

As an illustration:

```
# Note values
values_list = [1, 0.5, 0.25, 0.125]

# Threshold to deal with floats. Or use the fractions package.
threshold = 0.01

result = []

for i in range(round(1 / values_list[0]) + 1):
    for j in range(round(1 / values_list[1]) + 1):
        for k in range(round(1 / values_list[2]) + 1):
            for l in range(round(1 / values_list[3]) + 1):
                if abs(i * values_list[0] + j * values_list[1] + k * values_list[2] + l * values_list[3] - 1) < threshold:
                    result.append([i,j,k,l])

print(result)
>>> [[0, 0, 0, 8], [0, 0, 1, 6], [0, 0, 2, 4], [0, 0, 3, 2], [0, 0, 4, 0], [0, 1, 0, 4], [0, 1, 1, 2], [0, 1, 2, 0], [0, 2, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0]]
```

In this way you have all the possible combinations stored in `result`, where `i * values_list[0] + j * values_list[1] + k * values_list[2] + l * values_list[3] == 1`. For the first result we can see that for example `0 * 1 + 0 * 0.5 + 0 * 0.25 + 8 * 0.125 == 1`, which is indeed the case.
Like @TomKarzes said, you could also use the `fractions` package instead of a threshold.

Furthermore, I think you are smart enough to find a way to make the number of values in the `values_list` variable, using a variable number of `for` loops.
Good luck with the second part of the question.